# set "user-data-dir" in selenium python for chrome driver in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium

I am using **selenium** **python** in **Ubuntu**.

```
chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

How to set **user-data-dir** in chrome_options in **selenium python** in ubuntu ?

Comment: [Here a question that can provide you with the right solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062789/how-to-load-default-profile-in-chrome-using-python-selenium-webdriver)