# Maintain Session in Different Instances of Webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, session, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm using a function that creates new instances of WebDriver, so that I can switch user agent strings for each instance. I'm wondering whether or not there is a way to maintain the browser session from instance to instance, so that I do not have to log back in to the website every single time a new WebDriver instance is created?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179420/can-i-run-selenium-chromedriver-with-cookies-from-actual-chrome-installation) question - using the same profile for each instances should solve your problem.

Comment: @skandigraun but then can i also switch the user agent string for each instance...?

Comment: @skandigraun yeah, using a profile doesnt work. i was already using a profile, although before i was creating a new profile every time id create a new instance. however, i just tried creating a global profile, which also doesnt work...

Comment: Have you investigated creating a cookie that looks like you've logged in already? This may or may not be possible, depending on the site.

Comment: @JeffC i have not, but this def seems like the only possible option thus far