# Selenium - How to point to existing log-in data

Tags: python, vba, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

I am building a scraper for a site using Selenium (VBA & Chromedriver). The problem is, I need to log into this site and stay logged in. With my 'normal' browser session, the log-in remains. In selenium, I understand that this is not the case and I need to 'add a cookie' or something.

I would like to **not** log in programmatically and save a cookie. That seems silly. Because my 'normal' browser already has these details saved SOMEWHERE (AppData??). I just don't know how to point this info to my Selenium driver in code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
To point the driver to your 'actual' chrome's user data:

```
driver.AddArgument ("user-data-dir=C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
```

source:  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179420/can-i-run-selenium-chromedriver-with-cookies-from-actual-chrome-installation)