# How To Set ChromeOptions (or goog:ChromeOptions) for Selenium::Chrome in Perl

Tags: python, perl, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

In Python, I could easily change the browser "navigator.webdriver" property to false, when using the local chromedriver with my local Chrome browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get([some url])
```

After the above, in the Chrome browser console, navigator.webdriver would show "false".

But I do not know how to translate the above to Perl. The following code would still leave the navigator.webdriver as "true".  So how do I implement the Python code above in Perl?  Is it possible (ideally without using the remote stand-alone selenium server)?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Chrome;
my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new(
   custom_args => '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled' );
$driver->get([some url]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "The following code does not work." Could you be more specific about how it doesn't work? Do you get an error? Please [edit] your question with the details.

Comment: After the Perl code, "in the Chrome browser console, navigator.webdriver would show TRUE", unlike the Python code which successfully turns navigator.webdriver to FALSE.  So how do I do the same in Perl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to use `extra_capabilities` with `goog:chromeOptions`

```perl
my $drv = Selenium::Chrome->new(
     'extra_capabilities' => {
         'goog:chromeOptions' => {
             prefs => { ... },
             args => [ 
                 'window-position=960,10', 'window-size=950,1180', # etc   
                 'disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled'
             ]
         }
     }
);
```

(I don't know how `disable-blink-features` relates to that "*navigator.webdriver*")

For the list of attributes available in the constructor, along with the `extra_capabilities`,  see [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver), from which [Selenium::Chrome inherits](https://metacpan.org/dist/Selenium-Remote-Driver/source/lib/Selenium/Chrome.pm#L9).

For Chrome-specific capabilities see ["Recognized capabilities" in chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/capabilities), and more generally see [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) and [W3C WebDriver standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/). <sup>†</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> Specifically

- [WebDriver Capabilities](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/) in Selenium docs, and
- [Capabilities](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#capabilities) and [extension ("extra") capabilities](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-extension-capability) in WebDriver standard

Comment: Thanks so much!  I don't really know why disable-blink-features affects navigator.webdriver either.  Saw it on the Internet, w/ Python examples.  But I need it in Perl.   (Sad that one could hardly find any Perl tutorials/examples these days...)   Ideally, I would also want navigator.webdriver=false for Selenium::Firefox.  It seems that cannot be done, unless marionette=0 which pretty much makes Selenium::Firefox useless.   Any thoughts on how to get navigator.webdriver=false for Selenium::Firefox?

Comment: @ShangZhang  How about `my $drv = Selenium::Firefox->new(marionette_enabled => 1, extra_capabilities => { 'moz:firefoxOptions' => { args => [ ... ] }});` ?  I don't know what exactly that `navigator.webdriver` is, perhaps that can be set to `false` directly?  There is quite a bit more that can be set up in the constructor. I'll add some links when i get to it.

Comment: @ShangZhang Added linkswhich hopefully help some with this issue, largely undocumented in Perl

Comment: Thanks @zdim.  I tried extra_capabilities => { 'moz:firefoxOptions' => { args => [ disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled ] }}) but failed.  This is to be expected, as disable-blink-features is Chrome specific?  navigator.webdriver is part of W3C WebDriver interface (https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/).   I don't have the first idea on how to set it to false directly.  That would be nice though.

Comment: What preferences can I pass in prefs => { ... }. Any documentation for the same?

Comment: @PrakashP  Did you actually go through the links I assembled here?  I forget as I haven't used this in a while and I can't search for you now but a quick look reveals that [one of the links](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/capabilities) suggests to see Preferences file in Chrome's user directory for examples.  I suppose then you test to see what actually works (and much of it may well be OK but probably not all).  There may well be more docs, or it may be that this detail in particular isn't documented in Perl docs

Comment: @zdim Thank you for that. I was able to figure out. But not working. I just want to enable all cookies as my applications talk with an another application and creates a session for interaction

Comment: @PrakashP Ah, cookies.  A google search ("_perl selenium and Chrome cookies_" for example) returns a lot of good-looking pages, but for what you are asking perhaps [this answer (to an SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34184699/4653379) is spot-on.  It's python but you can see that they add and argument `user-data-dir` (the other answer on this page does that, too).  Try that?  I mean, an "argument" (`args => [ ... ]`), not a `prefs`.  If args doesn't do it then try prefs