# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service

Tags: google-chrome, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I had a trouble when i use selenium to control my Chrome.
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

When i tried to operate it ,it runs successfully at first,the Chrome pop on the screen. However, it shut down at the few seconds.
[image: Here is the Traceback information]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe')
  File "C:\Users\35273\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\35273\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 86, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\35273\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 99, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to provide the path of chromedriver...download from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/...unzip it and provide path to it in... webdriver.chrome ("path to chromedriver")

I explain the things here:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
```

This is the error if i run the above code:

```
    C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Gaurav.Gaurav-PC/PycharmProjects/Learning/StackOverflow/SeleniumQuestion/test123.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Gaurav.Gaurav-PC/PycharmProjects/Learning/StackOverflow/SeleniumQuestion/test123.py", line 4, in <module>
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
        self.service.start()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 86, in start
        self.assert_process_still_running()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 99, in assert_process_still_running
        % (self.path, return_code)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google

\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Which is same as mentioned by @Weiziyoung in original problem.

The solution is as I mentioned you need to provide the path to chromedriver in place of chrome browser like

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\Jars\chromedriver.exe")
```

It will resolve the problem

Comment: OP doesn't need to specify direct path to file as seems that `chromedriver` is already in the `Path`. In case of `chromedriver` binary not found something like `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable
 needs to be in PATH.` should be raised

Comment: No,i have added the path to the enviorment varitable.

Comment: I Think  its given the path of chrome browser not chromedriver in error line 1 you can see it

Comment: You think WRONG! This should be a path to `chromedriver`, not a `Chrome` binary. Check this: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Comment: I am sorry if I was not able to write properly to explain my point.  I m saying it looks the path of chrome binary is given inplace of chromedriver by the user looking at error

Comment: @Andersson I have updated my answer to prove my point of providing path of chromedriver

Comment: For the record, anyone reading this: I had path to CHROMEDRIVER_PATH and CHROME_BIN very clearly setup in my environment variables (evidenced by `printenv` and `import os` `os.environ` from the python shell. AND IT STILL WASN'T WORKING. And after an hour of frustration I gave up and rebooted my computer and VOILA, chromedriver now working.

Answer (score 0):

Download the appropriate driver：http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
turn up E:\Python37\Scripts <--Paste the chromedriver.exe file in

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same error (behave.step_registry.AmbiguousStep: @given('Lunch chrome Browser') has already been defined in   existing step @given('Lunch chrome Browser') at features/steps/OrangeHRMlogin.py:4). i think it takes previous program where it mentioned "Lunch chrome browser". so i did some changes like in 2nd program i cahnged at (U'chrome browser').change the browser name or the Phase and it runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

the original chrome browser is opened instead of chrome driver that's the reason of that error download chrome driver and give it's path