# WebDriverIO: Starting Chrome with browser sessions & cookies

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

Is it possible to run a WebdriverIO test case with Google Chrome, without creating a *"private Chrome window"* (*no cache or cookies*).

I want to start the Chrome browser I want to use the cookies and cache from Chrome, not a completely default state

**Scenario:** I am logging into our back-end on Chrome, which sets a token that I use on my localhost. When I run a test through Webdriverio, it doesn't have the token and I have to go through the login process once more.

So, in the terminal, if I run open `http://localhost:3001`, Chrome will open the application without needing to log in again.

**!Note:** I don't want to go through a login process on my tests... I just want to use the session token stored in Chrome after I login manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it shouldn't shock you that a test tool starts from a blank state browser. Who would want the testing context to be polluted by previous browsing, settings, cookies, etc? Secondly, I find it a bit funny that you want to automate a task, but don't care to automate 3-5 more steps to execute a successful login.

---

If you have some extensive level of configurations that need to be added to your Chrome instance (*cookies, local storage, extensions, users & passwords*), then custom [Chrome Profiles](https://www.chromium.org/developers/creating-and-using-profiles) is what you're looking for.

1. Identify where Chrome is storing the **Default** folder

You are basically trying to spawn Chrome with a specific set of configs. These are usually kept into the **Default** folder (*path: `/Users/YourUserHere/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`*).

**!Note:** This path might differ from OS to OS, so the recommended way to find out where Chrome is storing these configs on your device is by opening a new Chrome tab & typing `chrome://version`. The setting we are looking for here is **Profile Path**.

2. Store the contents of your **Default** folder in your designated assets folder
3. Add the path to your custom Chrome configs via the `--user-data-dir` [Chromium CLI switch](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/):

---

```
'goog:chromeOptions': {
// 'moz:firefoxOptions': {
  args: [ '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--start-fullscreen',
          '--disable-notifications',
          '--user-data-dir=/Path/To/Your/CustomConfigsFolder',
        ],
   }
}
```

4. Run your test with `browser.debug()` & check the configs have been successfully imported.

**Note:** I think I tackled this in a more generic sense on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213119/how-to-design-a-scraper-for-companies-such-as-owler/44213599#44213599) answer. Check it out, maybe it further helps in setting this up.