# How to fill login prompt with Webdriver IO?

Tags: node.js, webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm working on a CLI with [OCLIF](https://oclif.io/). In one of the commands, I need to simulate a couple of clicks on a web page (using the [WebdriverIO framework](https://webdriver.io/) for that). Before you're able to reach the desired page, there is a redirect to a page with a login prompt. When I use WebdriverIO methods related to alerts such as `browser.getAlertText()`, `browser.sendAlertText()` or `browser.acceptAlert`, I always get the error `no such alert`.

As an alternative, I tried to get the URL when I am on the page that shows the login prompt. With the URL, I wanted to do something like `browser.url(https://<username>:<password>@<url>)` to circumvent the prompt. However, `browser.url()` returns `chrome-error://chromewebdata/` as URL when I'm on that page. I guess because the focus is on the prompt and that doesn't have an URL. I also don't know the URL before I land on that page. When being redirected, a query string parameter containing a token is added to the URL that I need.

A screenshot of the prompt:

[image: prompt]

Is it possible to handle this scenario with WebdriverIO? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, probably there are some fine-tunings that you need to address to get it working.

First off, regarding the `chrome-error://chromewebdata` errors, quoting Chrome DOCs:

> If you see errors with a location like `chrome-error://chromewebdata/`
>   in the error stack, these errors are not from the extension or from
>   your app - they are usually a sign that Chrome was not able to load
>   your app.
>
> When you see these errors, first check whether Chrome was able to load
>   your app. Does Chrome say "This site can't be reached" or something
>   similar? You must start your own server to run your app. Double-check
>   that your server is running, and that the url and port are configured
>   correctly.

A lot of words that sum up to: Chrome couldn't load the URL you used inside the `browser.url()` command.

I tried myself on [The Internet - Basic Auth](https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth) page. It worked like a charm.

1. URL without basic auth credentials:

[image]

2. URL WITH basic auth credentials:

[image]

3. Code used:

```
  it('Bypass HTTP basic auth', () => {
    browser.url('https://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth');
    browser.waitForReadyState('complete');
    const banner = $('div.example p').getText().trim();
    expect(banner).to.equal('Congratulations! You must have the proper credentials.');
  });
```

What I'd do is manually go through each step, trying to emulate the same flow in the script you're using. From history I can tell you, I dealt with some HTTP web-apps that required a **refresh** after issuing the basic auth `browser.url()` call.

---

Another way to tackle this is to make use of some custom browser profiles ([Firefox](https://www.guru99.com/firefox-profile-selenium-webdriver.html) | [Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/developers/creating-and-using-profiles)) . I know I wrote a tutorial on it somewhere on SO, but I'm too lazy to find it. I reference a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213119/how-to-preserve-login-tokens-in-automation-for-websites-like-owler/44213599#44213599).

Short story, manually complete the basic auth flow (*logging in with credentials*) in an incognito window (*as to isolate the configurations*). Open `chrome://version/` in another tab of that session and store the contents of the **Profile Path**. That folder in going to keep all your sessions & preserve cookies and other browser data.

Lastly, in your `currentCapabilities`, update the browser-specific options to start the sessions with a custom profile, via the `'--user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile`. It should look something like this:

```
'goog:chromeOptions': {
    args: [
        '--user-data-dir=/Users/iamdanchiv/Desktop/scoped_dir18256_17319',
    ],
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem was that I did not know the URL of the basic auth page up front because of several redirects happening. The example flow would be something like "click login button" -> redirect -> redirect -> redirect (some token gets added to the URL here) -> basic auth page.

Your suggestion with the custom browser profile worked like a charm. I ended up using another solution however. I switched to the `devtools` protocol and turned on request intercepting before the redirects. At the point where the token gets added, I added the credentials in the URL to log in.

Comment: Nice work @KajNelissen! The devtools solutions sounds cleaner & more precise indeed, as tokens stored in custom profiles will eventually expire, or change altogether.

Comment: @KajNelissen i know this is old but could you share how you did it?