# Is there any way to automate a js prompt with two inputs using WebdriverIO?

Tags: automation, webdriver-io

I want to automate a login flow that prompts what is shown in the image attached. Is there any way to automate the input of both values using `WebdriverIO`?

This is the `Js` prompt:

[image: This is the Js prompt]

Im kinda new to `WebdriverIO`, encountered this prompt and im stuck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62298883/how-to-fill-login-prompt-with-webdriver-io