# driver.get not working when opening chrome driver with cookies

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use selenium on OSX to open a chrome window with existing cookies so that I can bypass login.  When I don't add the argument 'chrome_options=option' to open chrome with my user settings, the driver.get function works fine and it opens a chrome window with no extensions loaded and browses to the url. But when I use the code as shown below, it simply opens chrome (with all extensions loaded) but does not browse to the URL.  Am I missing something simple?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./assets/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/")
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a newline in `user-data-\ndir`?

Comment: yes, it is all on a single line

Comment: thanks.  I've updated the code above.  It now has everything that is in my py file.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load default profile in chrome using Python Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062789/how-to-load-default-profile-in-chrome-using-python-selenium-webdriver)