# How to persist Tampermonkey script in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run a JS script before the page load, so I have put it in tampermonkey. But the script doesnt persist after driver close. If I run the code again, the saved script is not there anymore. This is the code running selenium in python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

opts = Options()
opts.add_extension("tampermonkey extension.zip")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=opts)
driver.get("url")
# Add the JS script in Tampermonkey in the browser manually
driver.close()
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using Tampermonkey instead of executing the script with `driver.execute_script()`?

Comment: @Dalvenjia I want to run a JS script before the page load. AFAIK, `driver.execute_script()` doesnt guarantee that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To persist any extension or particular settings after a driver "recycle" your only option is to have a custom profile already configured with whatever you need and tell selenium to use that profile.

In Chrome here's a good answer: [How to load default profile in chrome using Python Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062789/how-to-load-default-profile-in-chrome-using-python-selenium-webdriver)

In Firefox is directly supported by Selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver see the first parameter to the `webdriver.Firefox()` constructor https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile