# WebDriverException Error when using selenium chrome webdriver with options

Tags: python, macos, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I would like to run the chrome webdriver on my MAC with my original chrome profile/options, so that i don't need to write a script to log in to the page in the temporary opened automated driver.

my original code without options was run successfully

```
DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
```

However, when I try to use options I get the following error, and here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/Victor/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome", chrome_options=options)
```

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0

So how may I fix this problem please?

Comment: please fix your import

Comment: what do you mean by fix the import? I do have from selenium import webdriver

Comment: in the code you posted

Comment: ok, i can add it, but i do have the webdriver import in my code

Comment: Corey, do you have a solution please?