# How can I do -> python, selenium and chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm using python and selenium to open a website and do something, but Chrome opens in incognito mode. I want to open in my user profile. How can I do this? (I'm using Ubuntu).

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--WHAT_HERE???")
chromedriver = "path_for_chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("LINK")
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/CL8kdxhgdj0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load default profile in chrome using Python Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062789/how-to-load-default-profile-in-chrome-using-python-selenium-webdriver)