# Using Chrome Addons in a Selenium Session possible?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

For a project of mine I decided to go with Selenium. It's a "scanner" for an web based online game, hence interaction with the page is needed. All things set and done I'm worrying for the security of my application and hence I took a look at well-known questions on SO. I found bunch of suggestions which may help securing the detectability of said programme.

What is left is something related to Chrome Plugins. In my Project File I got the chromedriver.exe and a dedicated resource folder for stuff like the cookies and settings it's supposed to run with. Now I want to run the Chromedriver.exe with Chrome Plugins.

**So is there any way to download Chrome Plugins in the Chromedriver.exe and run them every time with the Selenium process?**

Answer (score 1):

First method is to create a chrome profile and load it with youre chrome plugins

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", 
chrome_options=options)
```

Read more here [How to load default profile in chrome using Python Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062789/how-to-load-default-profile-in-chrome-using-python-selenium-webdriver)

another method is to add it in the chrome options:

```
options.add_extension('./exampleOfExtensionDownloadedToFolder.crx')
```

Answer (score 0):

To download the chrome extension, follow below steps.

1. add chrome extension.
2. Go to http://chrome://extensions/]
3. Enable developer mode.
4. Click on 'Details' of desired extension.
5. Click on 'Pack Extension'.
6. Browse extension root directory. Eg. C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd\3.17.0_0 ( Don't forget to sort the folders by date and select latest folder.)
7. Click on 'Pack Extension'.( If any error get encountered related to key browse manifest.json file from step 6 path)
8. Browse to extension path (Eg. C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd ) you will find .crx and .pem file.
9. Copy and paste both the files in resources folder of your project.

Below java code will help you to access the extension.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addExtensions(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\5.6_0.crx"));
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```