# How to use Chrome profile in Selenium (selenium-webdriver) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Since there doesn't seem to be a way to use an existing Chrome window, how do I use the Google account (and all settings and passwords) of the user in the window that `Selenium` opens? `Selenium` seems to open windows for itself, but without a Google account, which is an essential part to my program.

My program is very time sensitive, so it needs to be logged in to the websites it accesses automatically, and the program is going to be used by multiple users.

Comment: You can do this by saving the cookies after you login, then later you can load them in your script. See this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver

Comment: lots of answers on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31063104/1387701

Comment: Also: "going to be used by mutliple users"? I'm not sure selenium is the tool you want to use.

Comment: If Selenium may not be the right tool, then what do you recommend? The functionality I require is to open links and click on elements on pages like buttons. I use node.js, by the way.

Answer (score 9):

```
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
var options = new chrome.Options();
    
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\robert.car\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
    
options.addArguments("profile-directory=Profile 1")

var driver = let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('chrome')
.setChromeOptions(options)
.build();
```

user-data-dir considers profile as default , and you don't have to specify that . If its something else specify it through profile-directory argument

**Step to create a profile:**

**open** : chrome://version in address bar

[image]

**copy** the user dir folder completely to eg c:\tmp\newdir

open the copied user data (newdir) and search for folder called Default . This is the profile folder.

**rename** the Default folder as "Profile 1"

**Now to use this :**

```
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=c:\\tmp\\newdir")

options.addArguments("profile-directory=Profile 1")
```