# how to get Selenium to get other tab information

Tags: python, selenium

As it stands and I speak under correction, selenium opens a "private" browser tab.

I wanted to know if there was any way to change that so that the selenium tab can benefit from other tabs that are open, i.e. not need to login because you are already logged in on another non-selenium tab

Comment: You can try and launch the browser using your own chrome profile so it wont be a "clean " instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062789/how-to-load-default-profile-in-chrome-using-python-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that Selenium loads up the default browser profile. If you use chrome or a chromium based browser, go to `chrome://version` and you should see a  heading called `Profile Path` copy that and add it to your program with the options method.
Here is a sample:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=path_to_chrome_profile") #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path_to_chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
```

Hope it helps. And yes, make sure you are signed into the account you want selenium to access when you check your path.