# Chromedriver and selenium making a guest account instead of using actual account

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get selenium chromedriver to access a specific account. I did what I read online but it is making and accessing a guest account instead:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

options.add_argument (r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\mainuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1');
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1");


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
driver.get('https://hoopshype.com/salaries/players/')
players = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="name"]')
```

I want it to access an already signed in google account. What should I do to make it do that?

Comment: You can always login again with Selenium

Comment: @crissal is there not a way to launch it directly in the account?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31063104/11647025)

Comment: @crissal still does the same thing, I got the code from that answer

Comment: @crissal nevermind, doing this solved my problem:
'options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\mainuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')'

Answer (score 0):

FIXED
Found the answer:

```
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\ricca\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
```

now it is refusing to go to the website though, ill see what the problem is there an fix it.