# How to use certain Chrome profile with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It's been 6 years since it was reported first: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/854

From here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started I try this code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(60) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

While it's launched go chrome://version/ and see:

> Profile Path   C:\Users\USERCU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir13280_930640861\Default

To set up certain profile I tried the code from here [How to load default profile in Chrome using Python Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062789/how-to-load-default-profile-in-chrome-using-python-selenium-webdriver)

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user123\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 16") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

But instead of using specified path it actually creates profile inside another profile's path so  chrome://version shows:

> Profile Path   C:\Users\usercuhuh\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 16\Default

So the problem is that \Default folder is automatically added to specified user-data-dir. How can I bypass it and launch actually profile 16?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all

---

**update your ChromeDriver to the latest version**

---

(This part is mandatory).
Then pass two arguments `--profile-directory=Profile 1` and `user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user123\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 16` to the Chrome binary

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 16')
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Hana\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\") #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

Note that in `user-data-dir` you should only pass the path of all profiles then the name of specific profile (Here, Profile 16) should be passed through `--profile-directory`

You can check out full source code named [PythonChromeProfile](https://github.com/hanabizhani/SeleniumWebDriver-Tiny_projects/tree/main/PythonChromeProfile) in [SeleniumWebDriver-Tiny_projects](https://github.com/hanabizhani/SeleniumWebDriver-Tiny_projects) on Github, Which I tested successfuly. Also you can read about creating Chrome profiles and find the path to that profile [Here](https://github.com/hanabizhani/SeleniumWebDriver-Tiny_projects/blob/main/PythonChromeProfile/ReadMe.md)

Comment: This: Note that in user-data-dir you should only pass the path of all profiles then the name of specific profile (Here, Profile 16) should be passed through --profile-directory

Comment: Thank you!
I also installed selenium 4.0.0rc1 as it implements CDP (and my purpose is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243355/how-to-fetch-specific-request-which-happened-when-i-open-an-url-in-a-webbrowser) But its documentation is empty yet: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/support_packages/chrome_devtools/ May be you can suggest where I find it?

Comment: I just know that you create a new thread. let me take a look

Comment: And one more thing I noticed: if you going to use for example profile 1 and profile 16 at the same time you would get error: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir and only launch specified Profile but do no more. So you should put desired profiles' folders you gonna use into different --user-data-dir

Comment: I have two profiles in `user-data-dir` path, and just call only profile 1 in `--profile-directory`. No Error raised for me

Comment: I got this error when I had profile 1 Chrome window launched and my code tried to use profile 16. And when I closed profile 1 Chrome window code runs without problems.