# Open original google chrome with selenium in python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open google chrome(which has saved my information like my username and passwords) instead of Chromedriver.exe .
I tried some ways like opening chrome profile via:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
# or ->options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir= C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default") 
#or-> options.add_argument("--user-data-dir= C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") 
web=webdriver.Chrome( executable_path="c:\\Users\\me\\.spyder-py3\\chromedriver.exe"  , chrome_options=options)
web.get('https://google.com')
```

and it didn't work.

also I tried `web=webdriver.Chrome( 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')` and this way opened original chrome but didn't go to the link .

please tell me a way for using original google chrome instead of chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem: [How to use certain Chrome profile with selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246191/how-to-use-certain-chrome-profile-with-selenium-python)

The exact call and arguments are a bit specific. If not, pleade post selenium version you are using (4.x is quite bew)