# How to disable password manager in chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, password-manager

I hope you are all having a good day.

I have been trying to disable the password manager bubble for the last 3 days now without any luck. The reeason why I want to disable it is because its interfeering with my selenium automation even though it's not supposed to. But since I don't need password manager for my automation I would like to disable it completely.

[image]

**What I have tried so far**

Below is a list with all the flags I could find related to password manager. Even after adding all of them it still shows the password manager.

```
'--credentials_enable_service=false '
'--profile.password_manager_enabled=false '
'--disable-save-password-bubble '
'--disable-fill-on-account-select '
'--fill-on-account-select=false '
'--username-first-flow-with-intermediate-values=false '
'--enable-show-autofill-signatures=false '
'--skip-undecryptable-passwords=false '
'--force-password-initial-sync-when-decryption-fails=false '
'--fill-on-account-select=false '
'--filling-across-grouped-sites=false '
'--ios-promo-password-bubble=false '
'--password-generation-experiment=false '
'--revamped-password-management-bubble=false '
'--passwords-import-m2=false '
'--forgot-password-form-support=false '
'--password-store=basic'
```

I have also looked at other similar questions in stackoverflow but they seem to be outdated with the new Chrome updates since all the flags that used to work are not even available anymore in Chrome.

```
chrome_opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {
     "credentials_enable_service": False,
     "profile.password_manager_enabled": False
}

chrome_opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_opt, executable_path=r'C:\chrome_path.exe')
```

I have also found a solution that inlolves modifying some values Window registry of Chrome that disables password manager completely but that's not optimal because it will also disable the password manager from my normal Chrome build.

Thanks everyone for your time :)

PS: Don't give me the: "This have been answered before." I have tried everything and nothing works anymore. I am looking for an up to date solution.

Answer (score 3):

If none of the options you tried above work for you, use `--guest` mode:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_opt.add_argument("--guest")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_opt)
```

If you try going to chrome://password-manager/passwords in Guest Mode, you'll see: "Password Manager is not available to Guest users".

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Michael Mintz.
After trying the flag the password manager bubble still appears.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're in Guest Mode? Go to chrome://password-manager/passwords and look for "Password Manager is not available to Guest users". If you don't see that, then the `"--guest"` option wasn't set.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide password manager, using @Michael Mintz suggestion, or you can create Profile for automation and turn off password manager in it. It's more time consuming operation, however, in profile you can easily turn on / off lots of another features by demand.

1. Create new profile in Chrome
2. Click on profile icon -> Click on key icon
3. Turn off checkbox `Offer to save passwords"
4. Locate your new Chrome profile directory (for example, on Mac it is `/Users/YourUser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`
5. Create new directory `UserData` in Chrome catalog
6. Copy your new profile inside this catalog
7. Pass created profile inside ChromeOptions

[How to turn off password manager in Chrome profile reference](https://allaboutcookies.org/how-to-turn-off-google-password-manager)

[How to correctly define Chrome profile reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63885366/20292589)

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
path = '/Users/YourUser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/UserData'
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={path}")
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 2')
```

Comment: I really like the workaround but I am not sure how to modify it for my use case. The reason I can't only use one profile is that I need new fingerprint data for each run to stay anonymous for my task. Using the same profile would get easily detected from the website. The reason I like the solution is that I might do some tests to see the difference between a profile that has the password manager turned on or turned off. If I find the difference then I might be able to replicate it so that for each browser profile I can add/remove the files that turn it on. I don't know if it's possible though.

Comment: @Speci you can clear cookies on load / use proxies, so site couldn't detect you. 
Not sure that site can know that the user is the same by profile without cookies data. You can try at least and see if it detects or not.